# Como chamar outra procedure ou function dentro do mesmo packge no oracle?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Tenho varaias procedures e functions dentro do mesmo package. 
Como posso fazer referencia a alguma dentro no meu código PL-SQL?

**PACKAGE**:   CAIXA1

**PROCEDURE**: FECHARCAIXA,SOMATOTAL

**FUNCTION**: TOTALNOTAS

Como posso referenciaR SOMATOTAL dentro de FECHARCAIXA ?

Comment: Basta chamar a função normalmente dentro do corpo da procedure. E.g., `some_var := TOTALNOTAS(x, y, z);`. Se você não está conseguindo fazer isso pode ser um problema de declaração ou na ordem das definições, fica mais fácil de te ajudar se você postar um exemplo de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você declarar os objetos apenas no package body, basta fazer a declaração na ordem para que a referência funcione (ou seja, declarar SOMATOTAL antes de FECHARCAIXA). Caso tu declare os objetos no package spec, pode chamar independente da ordem. Exemplo usando a declaração no spec:

```
create or replace package CAIXA1 is

  procedure FECHARCAIXA;

  procedure SOMATOTAL;

  function TOTALNOTAS return number;

end CAIXA1;

create or replace package body CAIXA1 is

  procedure FECHARCAIXA is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('FECHARCAIXA');
    SOMATOTAL;
  end;

  procedure SOMATOTAL is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('SOMATOTAL');
  end;

  function TOTALNOTAS return number is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('TOTALNOTAS');
  end TOTALNOTAS;

end CAIXA1;

exec CAIXA1.FECHARCAIXA;
```

Output esperado:

```
FECHARCAIXA
SOMATOTAL
```